# Could I use multiple AWS Cognito app clients to give API access to my users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jwt, authorization, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

So, I know the answer is "yes I can", but is this the right path?

I have a Cognito userpool within all my platform users, now we would like to open specific API Gateway endpoints to specific users, so I just thought about using a Cognito app client for each user who wants these special access.

If a user wants to use the API will need an app client setup with its id/secret keys, then I can create an authorizer in the API Gateway pointing to this userpool and add it to specific endpoints.

Then the user will use his/her id/secret keys to generate a token to be used against specific API endpoints.

This seems to be clean and neat, but there is a big problem: **Cognito limits to 10k app client per userpool**

We don't actually have so much users wanting to access our API but who knows in the future.

So is this still the right path?

Comment: Why don't you just add an attribute to users and check that in a lambda authorizer?

Comment: I could but then the user has to use the same username/password for frontend login and backend API authentication, that's not so good. I would like to separate them.